# Having trouble with a JavaScript function being called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've got a web form I am working on where the user is able to do reviews. I print out a table with rows. The first row is a drop down of things to review, the second row are a set of questions, third row are drop down boxes with the scale for each question (1-5), and the final row is a hidden text box that appears when one of the questions is given a rating of less than 3. I am having problems getting the text box row to appear and can't figure out where the problem is. A majority of this information is being called from a database. I am using HTML, JavaScript, and PHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The user is available to dynamically create new tables/review forms when a button is clicked.

Code from the main PHP file:

```
<script language="javascript">
i=1;
function addCourse(){
    var table=document.getElementById("courseList");
    var clnNode=document.getElementById("courserow").cloneNode(true);
    var clnNode2=document.getElementById("questionRow").cloneNode(true);
    var clnNode3=document.getElementById("ratingSelects").cloneNode(true);  

    This clones the comments box that I want to get to pop up if the user choses a value less than three. 
    var clnNode4=document.getElementById("genComments").cloneNode(true);
    table.insertBefore(clnNode,table.lastChild);
    table.insertBefore(clnNode2,table.lastChild);
    table.insertBefore(clnNode3,table.lastChild);
    table.insertBefore(clnNode4,table.lastChild);
}

</script>

<!--    This contains the button to call the add course function from above.-->

             <button type="button" onclick="addCourse()">Add Another Student</button>

              <input name="finish" class="btn" type="submit" value="Finish Evaluation" />
              <div class="table-wrapper" style="height:550px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">
                 <table >
                <tbody id="courseList">
                   <?php printStartingRowsRe2();?>  
                </tbody>
                 </table>
              </div>
```

A majority of the  functions are in a seperate file. In the separate file, I have the document ready JavaScript code for the pop up box. A text box should appear if a drop down value of less than 3 is chosen.
Here is the script:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value < 3) {
            $("#genComments").show(); //You can see it is called "genComments"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the code from the function (also in the separate file) that originally prints the rows (printStartingRowsRe2) that originally prints everything, featured in the set of html code above.
You can see that I have the table row identified with 'ratingSelects', which also gets called in the "addCourse" function above. `ratingSelects` prints with no problems.

```
for ($xint=0; $xint<8; $xint++){
    print('<td><select name="numRating[]">  
        <option value="1">Poor</option>
        <option value="2">Less Than Acceptable</option>
        <option value="3">Satisfactory</option>
        <option value="4">Very Good</option>
        <option value="5">Excellent</option></select></td>');
}
print("</tr>");
print("<tr id='genCommments'> 
    <td style='display:none;' id='genComments'>
    <input type='text' class='text' placeholder='You gave a rating of less than 3 in one or more categories. Please provide a brief explination as to why.' />
    </td>
    </tr> ");
```

EDIT: Here is more of the code that shows the row that my pop up box should be working with:

```
print("<tr id='ratingSelects'>");
for ($xint=0; $xint<8; $xint++){
    print('<td><select name="numRating[]">  
        <option value="-">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Poor</option>
        <option value="2">Less Than Acceptable</option>
        <option value="3">Satisfactory</option>
        <option value="4">Very Good</option>
        <option value="5">Excellent</option></select></td>');
}
print("</tr>");

print("<tr id='genComments'>");
print("<td style='display:none;' colspan='8' id='genComments'>");
print("<input type='text' class='text' placeholder='You gave a rating of less than 3 in one or more categories. Please provide a brief explination as to why.' />");
print("</td>");
print("</tr> ");
print("<br>");
```

Comment: `$('select')` this is saying "everything on the page that is a select box"... not just the ones that are for rating (ie where `< 3` actually makes sense). Perhaps put a specific class/id on the select that matters and use that in your selector instead? Secondly... is the value `3` or `"3"` ? Thirdly: have you looked in the javascript console for errors?

Comment: @TarynEast I did not think about that in regards to the select box. I have been messing around with the code but still no avail... I added the table row of dropdown options that I am wanting the text box to respond to. It has the specific ID of `numRating[]` but I can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: `numRating[]` is not an id, it's a `name` - there's a difference. Use an id eg `id="num_rating123"`